# if i type Easter Bunny in textbox1 it needs to be shown 10x on label1. i need to use the While Statement

Tags: c#, while-loop

My question is about.

if i type easter bunny it needs to get shown 10x using the while statement.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int paashaas = 0;
        int p = paashaas;
        while (p <= 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The value of i is : " + paashaas);
            paashaas = paashaas + 1;
        }
    }
```

This seems unreal to me

Comment: I don't have any idea of what's the actual question in this.

Comment: Where is the `10` in the code? Where is `Label1`? Unclear question to me.

Comment: You do know that this is an infinite loop? p never changes!

Comment: Yeah its also a lil unclear for me. to clear it up a little.

when i type in textbox1 : Easter bunny. then it needs to detect easter bunny and puts on label1 Happy Easter.

Comment: @ZiggyManZiggyMan so what? What is your problem? How is that related to your original question (well, question, actually code that you have posted)?

Comment: there must be a real Easter egg in the system. If you enter the name of the patient "Easter Bunny" you must appear 10 times a MessageBox "Happy Easter". Like a loop.

Comment: my code is false that is clear to me

Comment: Your loop is also going to run forever the way you currently have it... you set `p = 0` and then never increment `p`

Comment: That is either an [X, Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or it's and homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing in the below code is:

- making an int (paashaas), setting it to 0,
- then making another int (p), setting the value of the second int (p) also to 0,
- then keep checking the second int (p) in the while loop, while changing the first int (paashaas) every time. Because of this, you will get stuck in the while loop. The value of p doesn't get changed, only the value of paashaas.

  ```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int paashaas = 0;
      int p = paashaas;
      while (p <= 4)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("The value of i is : " + paashaas);
          paashaas = paashaas + 1;
      }
  }
  ```

Also, i would use a for loop if i were you, if you want to do a certain action x times. For example take this code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The value of i is: " + i);
}
```

This code will show 4 message boxes, with the text:

- The value of i is: 1
- The value of i is: 2
- The value of i is: 3
- The value of i is: 4

I think the working code that you're looking for is:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text == "easter bunny")
        {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"You entered easter bunny in the textbox! {i}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you im sorry for my unclear Code its also my first time on stackoverflow this is working i wanna thank yu ;)